# Only last graph is getting pasted in pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf

I am reading the parameters from different CSV files and creating the graphs after comparing the parameters across the CSVs. The problem is only last graph is getting pasted in PDF for the last parameter.

```
    with PdfPages('example.pdf') as pdf:
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
            file_reader= open(arg, "rt", encoding='ascii')
            read = csv.reader(file_reader)

            for row in read:
                if  operation_OnDut in row:
                    column_Result = row[10]
                    resultOfOperations_OnDut_List.append(column_Result)
                    buildNumber = row[0]
                    buildName_List.append(buildNumber)




        N = len(resultOfOperations_OnDut_List)
        ind = np.arange(N)                  
        #Draw graph for operations performed in that TEST CASE
        y = resultOfOperations_OnDut_List


        width = .1

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        plt.bar(ind, y, width, label =  column_Parameters, color="blue")
        plt.xticks(ind, buildName_List)

        plt.title("Performance and Scale")
        plt.ylabel('Result of Operations')
        plt.xlabel('Execution Builds')
        plt.legend()
        plt.tight_layout()

        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()
        resultOfOperations_OnDut_List =     []
        buildName_List =                    []
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably got the indentation wrong...

Try

```
with PdfPages('example.pdf') as pdf:
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
            file_reader= open(arg, "rt", encoding='ascii')
            read = csv.reader(file_reader)

            for row in read:
                if  operation_OnDut in row:
                    column_Result = row[10]
                    ....


            # one level deeper
            N = len(resultOfOperations_OnDut_List)
            ind = np.arange(N)                  
            #Draw graph for operations performed in that TEST CASE
            ...
```

Note that the section starting with `N = len(resultOfOperations_OnDut_List)` has been shifted four spaces to the left to be within the first for loop. If you want it to be within the second for loop add four more spaces.